# How do I make portrait mode in Firefox also work with the behaviors in Chrome, and Opera?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am working on a responsive image viewer in which I would like to use flexbox, jQuery and bootstrap.  So far, I am working on getting the viewer to re-map when the screen is resized. (Later I plan to put it in a modal dialog.) The page is at: outtopastureenterprises.com/exper/modal/view2.html

I would like the page to have a large black box surrounded by some buttons.  It does this in landscape mode but portrait mode is broken. The min-height property doesn't seem to do anything.

Anyway, I am new at flexbox and would be very grateful for any advice or help.  Thanks.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta  charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>VIEWER</title>
        <style>
          #container {
          display: flex;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
          }
          #display {
          background-color: black;
          }
          .btn {
          font-size: 400%;
          font-family: 'cursive';
          text-align: center;
          min-height: 48px;
          min-width: 48px;
          }

          #minus { color: pink; margin: auto; text-decoration:line-through; }
          #plus { color: red; margin: auto;}
          #info {  margin: auto;
                  font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; color: white;
          }
          #comment { background-color: green; }
          #comment-button {  }

      @media screen and (orientation: landscape ){
          #yes { 
              order: 2; 
              -webkit-order: 2; 
              width: 10%; 
              margin:auto; 
          }
          #no { 
              order: 0; 
              -webkit-order: 0; 
              width: 10%; 
              margin:auto;
          }
          #minus {  width:80%; margin-left:-10%;margin-top: 100%; margin-bottom: 100%; }
          #plus { width:80%; margin-top: 100%; margin-bottom: 100%;}
          #info { width:80%; margin-top: 100%; margin-bottom: 100%;}
          #comment { 
                display: none; 
                order: 3;
                -webkit-order: 3;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 16px;
          }
          #comment-button { width: 80%; margin-top: 100%; margin-bottom: 100%;}
          .comment-button { width:"80%"; }
          #display {
             order: 1;
             -webkit-order: 1;
             min-width: 80%;
             min-height:100%;
          }
      }
      @media screen and (orientation: portrait ){
          #yes {
                display: flex;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                margin:auto; 
                width: 60%;
          }
          #no { width: 30%;
                margin: auto;
                display: flex;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
          }
          #minus { order: 1;
                   -webkit-order: 1; 
                   width:60%;
          }
          #plus { order: 3; 
                 -webkit-order: 3; 
                 width:30%;
          }
          #info { order: 2; 
                 -webkit-order: 2; 
                 width:30%;
          }
          #comment { order: 4; 
                    -webkit-order: 4; 
                    width: 100%; 
                    min-height: 48px;
          }
          #comment-button { display: none; }
          #display {
             order: 0;
             -webkit-order: 0;
             width: 100%;
             height:80%;
             min-width: 100%;
             min-height:80%;
          }
       }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id='container' >
      <div id='display'></div>
      <div id='no'>
          <!--<div id='minus' class='btn'><a class="prev" >&#9829;</a></div>--><!--downarrow: &#8595; -->
          <div id='minus' class='btn'><a class="prev" ><img src="notHeart.png"/></a></div>
          <div id='comment-button' class='btn' title="Click for comments">
            <img  src="79-bubble-comment-streamline-talk.png"/>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id='yes'>
        <div id='plus' class='btn'><a class="next" ><img src="heart.png"/></a></div> 
        <div id='info' title='Information' class='btn'>
            <a class="next" ><img  src="information.png"/></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <input id='comment' type='text' value='comment goes here'></input>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I would like to know how to make the behavior in firefox (in portrait mode) agree with the behavior in Chrome or Opera.

Comment: `flex` has limited browser support specially mobile browsers like `Opera-mini`

Comment: I realize, but it is working on Android with webkit, and from what I have read it should work on firefox.  I understand that leading edge == bleeding edge

Comment: You should remove the <html5> tag as it is not correct html. Please refer to [this boilderplate example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp) for the correct definition of a html5 document

Comment: @LenB then you should've asked the question I asked on it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jackson , I corrected the html and now none of the browsers behave as I think they should in portrait mode.  But at least they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be do to the fact that in portrait mode, the #display div is the only thing on the top row.  Specifying the lengths using viewport dimensions, vh and vw, solves the problem.